# пересечение адресов глобальных двумерных массивов

Tags: c, mingw

где-то в начале .cpp файла объявлены 4 двумерных массива

```
#define NUM_OBJ 8
float array1[NUM_OBj][NUM_OBJ];
float array2[NUM_OBj][NUM_OBJ];
float array3[NUM_OBj][NUM_OBJ];
float array4[NUM_OBj][NUM_OBJ];
```

В определенный момент было обнаружено, что 3 массив пересекается адресами с 1 строкой второго (т.е при дебаге я увидел, что при заполнении массива 3, заполняется и первая строка массива 2).

Ранее всегда избегал работы с глобальными переменными, но достался чужой код на чистом С. Подскажите, из-за чего может возникать подобная ситуация?
MinGW 5.3.0

Comment: #pragma pack есть?

Comment: Объявлены вот так, все 4 по отдельности, и в одной области видимости? Как заполняется? обычным присваиванием `array3[0][0]`, грубо говоря, или через передачу в функцию?

Comment: Скорее всего где-то топчятся массивы ваши, либо приведите явные доказательства пересечения

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , и правда, помогло. почему так? я обычно только структуры выравниваю, а здесь то это причем?

Comment: @Harry , обычным присваиванием, через аргументы функции ничего не передается. Как выше указал Владимир, дело в выравнивании. Не понимаю, правда, почему)

Comment: @bronstein87 если pragma pack помогло - значит либо компилятор чудит, либо где-то в другом месте прагма тоже стоит и мешает (что более вероятно).

Comment: а может просто компилятор пересобрал все, а до этого "забывал".

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов стояло две прагмы перед, но они выравнивали структуры и были закрыты, так что на массивы никак повлиять не могли, если я всё правильно понимаю

Comment: Значит, дело в прагмах :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и как вообще тогда такое предусматривать или бороться? в чем суть проблемы вообще? дайте пожалуйста развернутый ответ, если вам нетрудно, заодно и отмечу как правильный

Comment: @bronstein87 я не знаю деталей вашей ситуации. Вероятно, некорректное использование прагм у вас.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , хорошо, а как тогда объяснить то, что я теперь убрал прагмы с массивов, скомпилировал заново, но проблема не объявилась вновь?

Comment: @bronstein87 Проблема может возникать или появляться :-) Минимальный воспроизводимый пример нужен

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А как pragma pack моожет к такому привести?

Comment: @Mikhailo Часть выровняли, часть невыровняли... Вот они и наложились. Но я детально не разбирался, знаю что такая проблема может быть.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Они никак не могут пересечься, как бы ни были объявлены - могут, скажем, занять больше места, но вряд ли. А уж наложиться один на другой точно - совсем не верится. Может, алиас какой?

Comment: @Mikhailo говорю же, не разбирался. Сталкивался - да, внятного объяснения почему оно так - нет.